# PriorityQueue in C#, what is the purpose of having both TElement and TPriority?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, priority-queue

I recently tried implementing MinHeap and MaxHeap using [`PriorityQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2) in C# (.NET 6). To my surprise, I see C# is expecting two parameters `TElement` and `TPriority`. It works well if we define the priority but there are some use cases where I need to insert a stream of Integers and want to use max-heapify and min-heapify.

I cannot always set priority on my own, I can provide a comparator, and then it should automatically call the max-heapify and min-heapify according to my comparator.

We might think for single integers why do we even want to use `PriorityQueue`, Can't we use `SortedSet`s, the problem with set is, it will not handle duplicates.

```
Priority Queue implementation in Java :
PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(10); //By Default MinHeap
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(10, Collections.reverseOrder()); //MaxHeap
```

```
PriorityQueue<School, int> queue = new PriorityQueue<School, int>();
for Integers :
var queue = new PriorityQueue<int, int>(Comparer<int>.Create((x, y) => y - x));
**queue.Enqueue(1);** //this results in an error, If I am providing the priority then what is the use of this collection
//To make it work
**queue.Enqueue(1, 10);** //this will work and here 10 is a random number for priority used.
```

I can add the same number for priority, but it should be handled gracefully within the collection. Basic OOPS concept (Abstraction)?

Why do I need to provide the priority, unless I want some custom implementation, I don't know if this is me who is not understanding this. Or Microsoft messed up this collection?

Comment: What [C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10) feature does this question relate to specifically?

Comment: Different concepts: in Java  a lambda function is used to compare two elements. While in C# each object takes a priority with a comparer to check priorities. In this specific case i would use a List<int[]> with LINQ to order by the first element.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator PriorityQueue, time complexity: O(1) for fetching, insertion, and deletion takes O(log(n)) but I believe Order by uses Quick Sort will be O(N logN) or O(N2) (worst case)

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama : Built-in PriorityQueue is only available with .net6 and C#10, so I thought to add

Comment: PriorityQueue is a feature of .NET, it's not a feature of the language. If I so desire, I can set my project up so that it uses .NET 6.0, but the C# language used it 2.0 (released way back in 2006). `PriorityQueue` works because it's a type, but stuff like LINQ syntax (`from x in array`, etc.)  doesn't because that was introduced in C# 3.0

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama : I understand that but can you choose a different language version while still using .net 6? Visual Studio automatically selects a language and does not allow you to change it. Please check on the properties tab. Why it is not allowed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: I can remove this tag if this is of much concern. I wanted to spread this with the community and wanted to understand the motive behind it.

Comment: You can. You edit the project file and add `<LangVersion>2</LangVersion>` and boom! You're working with C# 2. It even tells you [how to do that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#override-a-default) on the page you linked to. The fact that the page you linked to says _"C# language version **default**"_ is surely evidence to you that you can use a different language version?

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. You can find the justification in the GitHub issue that introduced the [`PriorityQueue<TElement,TPriority>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2) collection, in a response by Eirik Tsarpalis to Miha Zupan:

> > > Priority ordinals are passed as separate values (rather than being encapsulated by the element)
> >
> > How come? Is it common to use a heap without having a custom node type? I'm just surprised by this one as I've always had the node perform comparisons.
>
> I think it is pretty common actually. When investigating our codebases I found many PQ implementations passing priority as a separate parameter. However even for queues ordering on the elements themselves, it was very common for consumers to populate the type parameter with a tuple containing an element and a priority, then use a custom comparer that projected to the priority. To me this seems like we might be forcing additional boilerplate just to encapsulate the priority.

Citation: [Developers can use a built in PriorityQueue type](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43957#issuecomment-718265734)

So the `<TElement,TPriority>` design was chosen for convenience. In case you don't need the `TElement`, unfortunately you'll have to either accept the performance overhead of moving around dummy `int` or `bool` values (as `TElement`s), or use a [third party](https://github.com/topics/priority-queue?l=c%23) implementation.